# Is there any way to show a message like account lockout for a non-existing user account for too many times wrong attempt in AD B2C?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

I'm working with AD B2C custom policy. I have set account lockout threshold and its working fine. Now i have a scenario that if a user trying to login with a non-existing user name, after a few try lets say 10 times is it possible to show a custom error message that "Too many in valid attempts"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Self-Asserted TP you can use the *setting.retryLimit* metadata

> Controls the number of times a user can try to provide the data that is checked against a validation technical profile . For example, a user tries to sign-up with an account that already exists and keeps trying until the limit reached.

So, if you have a validation technical profile that is in charge of validating the non-existing username, after *setting.retryLimit* retries your application will receive a specific error

> AADB2C90157: User has exceeded the maximum number for retries for a self-asserted step.

You could intercept that in your application and show a custom message to the user.

EDIT:

If you want to show the error on the Self-Asserted page itself, you could put a RESTful validation technical provider (i.e. An Azure Function) right after the authentication one. If the user is found, you'll have the objectId and you could even skip the call to the Azure Function. If the objectId is empty, you'll call the Azure Function passing the signin name and store the new attempt somewhere (Azure Table Storage?). Whenever you non-existing user reaches the limit, you'll return a 409 with a custom message. That message will be shown on the Self-Asserted page.
I didn't try it, but logically it could work. You have to tweak the *setting.retryLimit* to avoid to come back to your application with an error before the custom message is shown.

HTH, F